# How to bypass modal window?

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm doing web-scraping with python and programmatically access a website. For this I use urllib and cookiejar. In my program

I'm doing a post query to a website to search for something. So normally I log in with OAuth, go to the search page to look for relevant items, then send the search query for interesting items.

However, every once in a while, seeming totally random, when I execute the search query for an item, I get a modal window as a response, something like "Check out our new search functions!". By this I mean the response content of the POST request is a HTML page that describes the modal window, whereas I would normally expect to receive a HTML page that contains the description of the item I was searching for.

How can I bypass this modal window and make the post request return as normal all the time? Am I supposed to set a cookie of some sort? I'm using urllib with cookiejar.

Comment: Sounds like the modal is generated by some sort of javascript (ie no url change happened). Does the modal appear before the search gets executed?

Comment: @Gevious If I do a post request with python, could javascript be executed? I'm getting the modal window as the content of the post request response.

Comment: I suppose javascript won't necessarily be executed, since you're not using a browser. If the server is something like node, it might be clever enough to include the modal in the first response. Without more info its hard to say. Do you have an example site?